# How do I move docker vm to SD card?

Tags: docker, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave

My mac is running out of disk space. I have a 256GB SD card which is always inserted (I never take it out). Can I configure 'Docker for Mac' to store all of its images/containers/configuration/... in the SD card instead of ~/Library/..? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store Docker image files in external drive in El Capitan OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205735/store-docker-image-files-in-external-drive-in-el-capitan-osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Docker Desktop Community version 2.0.0.0-mac81,

[image]

the functionality to move disk image location is built into the UI (in Preferences).

[image]

My docker.cow file was about 50GB and it took about 10 minutes to move it.

Comment: Keep in mind it wont work if the partition is Fat32.