# Moving docker data directory

Tags: docker, centos7

I want to store docker data on an external disk following the documentation on [daemon.json](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) configuration.

Error:

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: data-root
```

- Using the documentation from [docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/), the "data-root" configuration option is used to move the data directory.
- Using the documentation from [docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/), the new disk satisfies the prerequisites of xfs format,`ftype=1` as per the output from `xfs_info /path/to/disk |grep ftype`

Using Centos7.9;

Stop docker

```
systemctl stop docker
```

Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to include:

```
{
        "data-root": "/var/lib/test"
}
```

Note; I found a source suggesting to add `"storage-driver": "overlay2"` to daemon.json - this has the same error at the top of this post

Sync the old and new directory

```
sudo rsync -axPSv /var/lib/docker/ /var/lib/test/
```

Start docker

```
systemctl start docker
```

Observe the error

```
systemctl status docker.service -l
```

```
localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[3615]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: data-root
```

I also tried using the `--bind` as suggested [here](https://opensource.ncsa.illinois.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=114130966), and also [this](https://tomthorp.me/blog/moving-docker-data-directory) info for centos and SELinux all resulting in the error posted here.

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205735/store-docker-image-files-on-external-drive-in-macos . Probably there must be a symlink.

Comment: Not sure where "com.docker.docker" is here.. Looks like I didn't mention it in the question, I'm looking for a solution for Centos not OSX.

Comment: I saw that you mentioned Centos in the question, but I thought there may be some clues in that article, despite the fact that it's for OSX. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am clueless -.-

Comment: See this: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_8&p=docker&f=5

Comment: This doco describes how to mount a directory into a docker container for persistent storage. I want to move the docker runtime storage from the default `/var/lib/docker` to another directory, lets say `/var/lib/test`. Docker here is only used for building images, there are no containers on this Centos VM.